# Constructors do not have return type in Java

Tags: java

IF constructors in Java does not return any value- they do not have any return type then when an object is created like

```
ClassOne objectOne=new ClassOne();
```

how a reference referring to the object of ClassOne is returned. IS it JVM which returns the reference.

Comment: Lookup the `new` keyword

Comment: "Constructors do not return any value"--that's really just how the compiler tells them apart from methods.  If something looks like a method, has the same name as the class, and doesn't have a return type (including `void`), it's a constructor.

Comment: Constructors do have a return type; what they don't have is a name :)

Comment: You can consider `new ClassOne()` as follows: `new ClassOne`, which allocates an object of type `ClassOne,` and `(...),` which calls a constructor. Your question about 'the JVM return[ing] the reference' is basically meaningless.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight your comment should be an answer to this question. i'd upvote :-)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight interesting way of looking at the constructor declaration :)

Answer (score 2):

Constructors **do** have a return type.  The return type is *implicitly* the type of the class that declares the constructor.

<sup>Or you could say that constructors have an explicit return type and no name.  Or, you could say that both the constructor name and the return type name are the same ... though that is *not strictly correct*.  (If you are really perverse you can actually declare a regular method whose name is the same as the class name, with an explicit return type.  But don't try this in any code that you want other people to read.  They will throw stones at you ....)</sup>

Granted, the type is not explicitly declared.  But it doesn't need to be.  (And if it was declared, people would complain *even more* about Java verbosity.)

---

Similarly, a `return` statement in constructor cannot have an expression.  That is because a constructor *implicitly* returns the reference to the object being constructed; i.e. `this`.

Answer (score 0):

When we say constructors don't have a 'return type' it is to mean that the developer does not need to put an explicit/direct return type or even the key word void in front of the constructor name.

A constructor is to be used with the 'new' keyword since the purpose of the constructor is to initialize the members of a class and put the newly created/instantiated object to the allocated memory space by the 'new' keyword. Finally, the constructor is supposed to give back the memory address (location) to the left side. To explain this better consider the following example.

```
Circle c;
c = new Circle();
```

1. the left side Circle c creates a pointer (object name or ref type c) to hold the memory address of instances of type (from class) Circle. Only memory address of Circle classes or their sub classes if there is/are are allowed to be stored in c.
2. new keyword creates a memory location for the object to be created
3. Circle() constructor will create the object, place the object to the allocated memory and then assigns the memory address to the reference 'c'.

If constructors do not return a value this assignment statement would be meaningless. In this case our constructor returns a memory address of instance of Circle.

In summary, when we say a constructor does not return a value, it is to mean that the developer is not required to place a return type in front of the Constructor name as it is the case with other methods.

Hope this helps,
Thanks

Comment: You say *"... when we say a constructor does not return a value ..."*.  In fact "we" don't say that at all.  Or at least, we *shouldn't* say it.  If we don't say incorrect things, then we don't need to explain them.

Comment: Concur Stephen. But many books put it simply as that. That is by what I want to mean.

Comment: So how do you downvote a book?  StackOverflow needs to give us a way to do that.

Comment: If a book says that, then the book is wrong.  "We" are not incorrect books.  "We" are free agents who aspire to be clear and accurate in what we say.  (And "we" write negative reviews for books that spout nonsense.  But not here ...)

Comment: @ajb - Sorry, no.  That is off-topic.  StackOverflow is a Q&A site on programming ... not a book recommendation or book review site.

Comment: @StephenC Sorry, I was joking.  Sometimes I forget that my twisted sense of humor isn't always obvious.  But I do get pretty frustrated by misinformation from books or professors or other places that are supposed to be authorities.  There have been lots of homework questions here where I've wished I could have downvoted the professors for giving out bad info or just plain stupid assignments.